# Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, yarnpkg, caniuse

I have 2 Next.js applications running with the same message error: `Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command 'yarn upgrade'`. The message shows up when I run commands like `yarn dev` or `yarn start` or `yarn build`. It's happening the same with NPM.

- I've tried the command (`yarn upgrade`) many times with no success;
- I've tried already to delete the lock files and also the node_modules but the message still;
- I've tried with both Visual Studio and Terminal (Ubuntu);

It was fine a couple of days ago so I'm not sure if it's related to some new package update.

Anyone else having the same?

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "website-2020",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanem/react-nprogress": "^3.0.24",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "^9.3.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-data-table-component": "^6.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "faker": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The message might not be impacting your project. In which case you could ignore it. But if it is an issue

`yarn upgrade` will obey the limits set in the package.json.
Carets in front of `^version` will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. e.g. ^2.3.4 will use releases from 2.3.4 to <3.0.0.

Try run `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`

This may error, but should at least tell you the latest version of caniuse-lite.

If it errored, then try `yarn why caniuse-lite`

This will tell you which dependencies are using **caniuse-lite** and which version they are using. You may need to run `yarn why <dependencyNameHere>` to trace those child dependencies back to a package listed in your package.json.

Then you can install the latest of each.
Hopefully this will fix your issue.